# I want to get the file on directory counting 21 previous days from today

Tags: excel, vba, file, excel-2019

I have a directory with subdirectories that contains monthly files archived.
I want to get the data from files from **subdirectory** counting 21 previous days from today and if is not in my current subdirectory, **then skip to previous subdirectory**.

The way I declared, brings me the content that I need, however with exactly the currently month, number corresponding of month, and year.

````
Sub getNumber(CM As String, shift As String, fileDate As String)
Dim newDate: newDate = Format(DateAdd("M", 0, Now), "MM-MMMM")
filePath ="\\bt\depthr\cement\trailer\Plans\Day Shift\05-May\trailer_flow_5-5-22 Day Shift Plan.xlsb\" & newDate & "\"
fileName = CM & "_" & "flow" & "_" & fileDate & "Plans" & ".xlsb"```
````

How can I correct it to bring me previous 21 days and skip to previous subdirectory if the 21 days includes previous month?

Thank you.

Comment: It would be useful to see sample directories and file names

Comment: \\bt\dept\cement\trailer\Plans\Day Shift\05-May\trailer_flow_5-5-22 Day Shift Plan.xlsb

Comment: Hi, this is just an example.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72203144/edit) to add information

Comment: Something like `myPath = "\\bt\dept\cement\trailer\Plans\Day Shift\" & Format(Date - 21, "MM-MMMM") & "\trailer_flow_" & Format(Date - 21, "m-d-yy") & " Day Shift Plan.xlsb"` maybe?

Comment: I am sorry, ok I edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244674/discussion-between-cybernetic-nomad-and-david-nunes).

Answer (score 0):

This will give you 21 days back date in VBA.

```
Dim newD As Date
newD = Date - 21
MsgBox newD
```

Comment: Yes it does!!! I got it!!! now I will need to create a if condition to take me back if the 21 days file is inside the last month directory.

Comment: Thank you Naveed. I am using your suggestion successfully.